# Pull to Refresh iOS App then Scroll

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

After pulling to refresh the question list, the Votes (or other sorting label) bar is offset by the height of the search bar. This is only while the refresh is loading. Once it's finished everything is right in the world.

[image]

Comment: Looking into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.