# Pull Down to Refresh on Home Page (iPad App)

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app

I see there are other questions about "pull to refresh" on questions. But I'm asking about on your user.

I am using the Beta, and I am on my home page (my user profile). Normally on an iOS app, you pull down to refresh the page. I can't seem to do that on this app.

Similarly related to: [Pull to Refresh iOS App then Scroll](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221576/pull-to-refresh-ios-app-then-scroll)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion – there are parts of the app where this was difficult to implement, but in this case it was doable.

This will be available beginning with beta version **1.1.0.127**